# how to run php automatically on apache

Tags: php, apache

I wanted to know if there was a way to configure Apache to automatically run a php script at a  particular time without need for me being online, as long as my server is active

Comment: I'll google for you :) https://www.google.com/search?q=cron+job+php

Comment: There isn't. What you need to do is to set up a *cron job* that will call Apache, e.g. using lynx, or directly your script.

Comment: you mean a cron job? [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). For Linux servers [Cron Linux Apache](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Cron Job` is what you are looking for, mostly your hosting provide you with this service, if you are using a `dedicated` server, you can generate a `cron` here http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/ or here is a little tutorial for it: http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

[Cron job](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron&ei=rDtVUquoFevL0AWY5IH4Cg&usg=AFQjCNFFJIlg-yvhmJjB9vc1tkJtgWkSCA&sig2=WKTB4VcL-vSrULSVnVdSdA) is what you'are looking for. A Generator [HERE](http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/)

Answer (score 0):

Read about http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial or write a daemon :)

Answer (score 0):

A cron is what you are looking for.

If you server is Linux, you can add an entry to your chrontab: http://www.tecmint.com/11-cron-scheduling-task-examples-in-linux/